# Prove $1/x + 1/y = 0$ is not linear.

Tags: quadratics

I was trying to complete an exercise of a book and tried to solve this question but wasn't able to succeed. I searched it on google but found no results related to this question. Please help.

Comment: For $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$, we can see that $f(2,2)=1\neq4=2f(1,1)$. This contradicts linearity immediately.

Comment: $1/x+1/y=0$ is the line $y=-x$ without the point $(0,0)$

Comment: What does this even mean? When is an equation linear? (It‘s clear that they probably want to hear something along the lines of J.W. Tanner...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y=0$ then $\dfrac1x=-\dfrac1y$ so $y=-x$, which is of the linear form $y=mx+b$ with $m=-1$ and $b=0$, but $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$ (because if $z=0$ then $\dfrac1z$ is undefined).  So the locus of points $(x,y)$ satisfying $\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y=0$ is a line with a point (the origin) missing.

Comment: depending on context, [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) means $y=mx$ or $y=mx+b$; $y=-x$ meets either of these definitions

Comment: But still why isn't it a linear as it meets all the conditions.

Comment: it's a line that's missing a point